# How to use monk initiated mongoDB instance in gridfs-stream?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, gridfs-stream

I'm using [`gridfs-stream`](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream). In the docs there is an example for a mongodb native DB:

```
// create or use an existing mongodb-native db instance.
var db = new mongo.Db('yourDatabaseName', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017))
// make sure the db instance is open before passing into `Grid`
db.open(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);
})
```

...and I'm using [`monk`](https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/manager/), which is also based on mongodb native driver.

Unfortunately I am not very familiar with implementation of mongoDB, so I'm not quite sure, if I can also use a monk connected db with gridfs-stream:

```
var db = monk('mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDatabaseName')
var gfs = Grid(db, mongo) // <-- what is mongo in this context?
```

...with this attempt I do not know from where to get `mongo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongo in this context is just mongodb, something like this:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb'),
      monk = require('monk'),
      monkMgr = monk('mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDatabaseName');

monkMgr.on("open", db => {
    const gfs = Grid(db, mongo);
});
```

It seems Grid uses the long deprecated `new mongo.Db(` instead of `MongoClient.connect` whilst monk relies on more recent version of the driver. I would expect some incompatibility. Just be aware of risks and invest extra time in testing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately I don't know an alternative to gridfs-stream. Maybe I should use the gridfs api of the native driver??

Comment: Well, take a look at https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream/issues, and decide whether it is acceptable for your needs. Sorry but *Maybe I should use ....* questions without any context of what you aim makes no sense, not mentioning they are off-topic here.

Comment: Is this the function you are talking about? https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream/blob/master/lib/index.js#L17 I don't see, where it uses the deprecated `new mongo.Db()``

Comment: `new mongo.Db()` is in your question.